# Simple Android alpha animation reversing when not declared

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create a simple fade out effect on a TextView. Having looked around SO, I couldn't see a similar issue posted.

I have a simple fade_out.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

And start the animation as so,

```
Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
textView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

The issue is that the TextView succesfully fades out, but it fades back in again. I must be missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:fillAfter="true"`. This will force a view to remember its state after animation finishes.

Comment: Great, thanks. I wish this was made more clear in the Animation guide!